# Nodejs returns the full JSON of the Blockchain Rates API but I can't access particular objects inside it. Why?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a file that makes a request to blockchain.info/ticker API in order to pull the latest price of bitcoin.

**script.js:**

```
let request = require('request');
let url = "https://blockchain.info/ticker"

request.get(url,
function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body); //first
    console.log(body.USD); //second
});
```

The first console.log statement inside the request.get returns:

```
{
  "USD" : {"15m" : 1034.99, "last" : 1034.99, "buy" : 1033.63, "sell" : 1034.99,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "ISK" : {"15m" : 116090.37, "last" : 116090.37, "buy" : 115937.82, "sell" : 116090.37,  "symbol" : "kr"},
  "HKD" : {"15m" : 8043.46, "last" : 8043.46, "buy" : 8032.89, "sell" : 8043.46,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "TWD" : {"15m" : 31374.69, "last" : 31374.69, "buy" : 31333.46, "sell" : 31374.69,  "symbol" : "NT$"},
  "CHF" : {"15m" : 1030.89, "last" : 1030.89, "buy" : 1029.53, "sell" : 1030.89,  "symbol" : "CHF"},
  "EUR" : {"15m" : 963.89, "last" : 963.89, "buy" : 962.63, "sell" : 963.89,  "symbol" : "€"},
  "DKK" : {"15m" : 7170.6, "last" : 7170.6, "buy" : 7161.17, "sell" : 7170.6,  "symbol" : "kr"},
  "CLP" : {"15m" : 685784.37, "last" : 685784.37, "buy" : 684883.24, "sell" : 685784.37,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "CAD" : {"15m" : 1380.41, "last" : 1380.41, "buy" : 1378.6, "sell" : 1380.41,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "CNY" : {"15m" : 7131.48, "last" : 7131.48, "buy" : 7122.11, "sell" : 7131.48,  "symbol" : "¥"},
  "THB" : {"15m" : 35634.71, "last" : 35634.71, "buy" : 35587.88, "sell" : 35634.71,  "symbol" : "฿"},
  "AUD" : {"15m" : 1349.36, "last" : 1349.36, "buy" : 1347.58, "sell" : 1349.36,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "SGD" : {"15m" : 1443.9, "last" : 1443.9, "buy" : 1442.01, "sell" : 1443.9,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "KRW" : {"15m" : 1155773.33, "last" : 1155773.33, "buy" : 1154254.62, "sell" : 1155773.33,  "symbol" : "₩"},
  "JPY" : {"15m" : 115110.38, "last" : 115110.38, "buy" : 114959.12, "sell" : 115110.38,  "symbol" : "¥"},
  "PLN" : {"15m" : 4072.84, "last" : 4072.84, "buy" : 4067.49, "sell" : 4072.84,  "symbol" : "zł"},
  "GBP" : {"15m" : 832.11, "last" : 832.11, "buy" : 831.01, "sell" : 832.11,  "symbol" : "£"},
  "SEK" : {"15m" : 9212.32, "last" : 9212.32, "buy" : 9200.21, "sell" : 9212.32,  "symbol" : "kr"},
  "NZD" : {"15m" : 1474.6, "last" : 1474.6, "buy" : 1472.66, "sell" : 1474.6,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "BRL" : {"15m" : 3232.68, "last" : 3232.68, "buy" : 3228.43, "sell" : 3232.68,  "symbol" : "R$"},
  "RUB" : {"15m" : 58287.38, "last" : 58287.38, "buy" : 58210.79, "sell" : 58287.38,  "symbol" : "RUB"}

}
```

The second console.log statement returns:

```
undefined
```

**What have I tried:**
I have tried to assign the same output that I get in the terminal to a variable in a chrome inspector and access different objects just to test out if my syntax is correct. Syntax is correct so, I'm really puzzled.

Why is my second console.log statement undefined and how can I fix this in order to get the "15m" price inside of the USD object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code fixed:

```
let request = require('request');
let url = "https://blockchain.info/ticker"

request.get(url, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body); //first
    console.log(JSON.parse(body).USD); // second
});
```

Request return the response as a JSON.
You have to parse it with `JSON.parse` in order to retrieve the USD attribute.

**Output**

```
{
  "USD" : {"15m" : 1034.66, "last" : 1034.66, "buy" : 1033, "sell" : 1034.66,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "ISK" : {"15m" : 116053.35, "last" : 116053.35, "buy" : 115867.16, "sell" : 116053.35,  "symbol" : "kr"},
  "HKD" : {"15m" : 8040.9, "last" : 8040.9, "buy" : 8028, "sell" : 8040.9,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "TWD" : {"15m" : 31364.68, "last" : 31364.68, "buy" : 31314.36, "sell" : 31364.68,  "symbol" : "NT$"},
  "CHF" : {"15m" : 1030.56, "last" : 1030.56, "buy" : 1028.91, "sell" : 1030.56,  "symbol" : "CHF"},
  "EUR" : {"15m" : 963.59, "last" : 963.59, "buy" : 962.04, "sell" : 963.59,  "symbol" : "€"},
  "DKK" : {"15m" : 7168.31, "last" : 7168.31, "buy" : 7156.81, "sell" : 7168.31,  "symbol" : "kr"},
  "CLP" : {"15m" : 685565.72, "last" : 685565.72, "buy" : 684465.8, "sell" : 685565.72,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "CAD" : {"15m" : 1379.97, "last" : 1379.97, "buy" : 1377.76, "sell" : 1379.97,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "CNY" : {"15m" : 7129.21, "last" : 7129.21, "buy" : 7117.77, "sell" : 7129.21,  "symbol" : "¥"},
  "THB" : {"15m" : 35623.34, "last" : 35623.34, "buy" : 35566.19, "sell" : 35623.34,  "symbol" : "฿"},
  "AUD" : {"15m" : 1348.93, "last" : 1348.93, "buy" : 1346.76, "sell" : 1348.93,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "SGD" : {"15m" : 1443.44, "last" : 1443.44, "buy" : 1441.13, "sell" : 1443.44,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "KRW" : {"15m" : 1155404.82, "last" : 1155404.82, "buy" : 1153551.1, "sell" : 1155404.82,  "symbol" : "₩"},
  "JPY" : {"15m" : 115073.68, "last" : 115073.68, "buy" : 114889.05, "sell" : 115073.68,  "symbol" : "¥"},
  "PLN" : {"15m" : 4071.54, "last" : 4071.54, "buy" : 4065.01, "sell" : 4071.54,  "symbol" : "zł"},
  "GBP" : {"15m" : 831.84, "last" : 831.84, "buy" : 830.51, "sell" : 831.84,  "symbol" : "£"},
  "SEK" : {"15m" : 9209.38, "last" : 9209.38, "buy" : 9194.6, "sell" : 9209.38,  "symbol" : "kr"},
  "NZD" : {"15m" : 1474.13, "last" : 1474.13, "buy" : 1471.76, "sell" : 1474.13,  "symbol" : "$"},
  "BRL" : {"15m" : 3231.65, "last" : 3231.65, "buy" : 3226.47, "sell" : 3231.65,  "symbol" : "R$"},
  "RUB" : {"15m" : 58268.79, "last" : 58268.79, "buy" : 58175.31, "sell" : 58268.79,  "symbol" : "RUB"}

}
{ '15m': 1034.66,
  last: 1034.66,
  buy: 1033,
  sell: 1034.66,
  symbol: '$' }
```

Comment: I'm aware of case sensitivity, dot notation and bracket notation. My question contained a typo, I was actually accessing the object correctly. What I'm trying to express is that the same code that you wrote in the reply returns undefined when you run it with node. Have you tried running the code?

Comment: Okay, what was returned is JSON. You have to use the fonction `JSON.parse` to transform it into a javascript object.
I edited my answser!

Comment: That was the issue, thank you so much for your time and for helping me out. Can I ask you one more question please before accepting the answer? The reply I get from the API is a string and not a JSON by default? That's why I need to convert it?

Comment: The JSON format is a string and by default, the request library send a request with a HTTP header `Accept: application/json`.
That's why you have a JSON (which is a string) as a response.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested case sensitivity? Javascript is case sensitive so you might have to use

```
console.log(body.USD);
```

tested it with some of my json objects and it seems to work like that

Comment: As I've said below, my code contained a typo so I apologize for that. I'm actually console logging **body.USD** which doesn't work. That's what got me super confused and made me ask for some help here :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no property "usd" in the object. Try the following:

```
console.log(body.USD);
```

Comment: Apologies, there was a typo in my code. I'm aware that there's no "usd" property in the object. What I wanted to express was that the code doesn't work with body.USD which is what confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(body.USD);`//case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Actually the property is "USD" not usd.

try this one

```
console.log(body); //first
    console.log(body.USD); //second
```

Comment: @wpnubsoup try it.. this will Helpful